# Syntax Question. What is the role of the word "what" in the sentence?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, relative-clauses, what

While reading articles, I came across this sentence.

> Mr. Rafsanjani, 82, was also regarded a protector of **what** was left of Iran’s marginalized reformist movement and others with more moderate views than the conservative hard-line clerics who hold sway in Iran’s security forces and judiciary.

I was wondering what the role of "what" is in this sentence. Does it serve as a relative clause modifying the "protector"?

Comment: Not quite. This is a 'fused relative' construction in which the antecedent and the relativised element are fused together in the single word "what", instead of being expressed separately as in simpler constructions. Thus "what was left of Iran's ..." is a noun phrase whose head is fused with the first element of the relative clause. The meaning is like that of the non-fused "...a protector of _that which was left of Iran's ..._". In a tree diagram, "what" would be assigned the category label 'pronoun' and the function label "head". (Btw, the noun phrase is complement of the preposition "of").

Comment: @BillJ Prezackly so ..

Comment: @BillJ Thank you so much. I think I am a little bit clear now. But it is so wired to consider "what was left of Iran's..." as a noun phrase, I mean, it is a full sentence with subject, object and verb(was). I was wondering can I regard "what" as a fused words by "someone who". What's more, this is a comparative construction. Does it the pronoun "what" compare with "conservative hard-line clerics"? You time will be appreciated, thank you so much!

Comment: No, the element beginning with "what" is not a full sentence. It does contain a relative clause, but relatives are subordinate clauses, not main ones. Any subjects, objects or verbs that it contains all belong in the subordinate relative clause. It may become clearer if you think of "what" as meaning "that which", where "that" is a pronoun (a subclass of noun), so we have the noun phrase _that which was left of Iran’s marginalized reformist movement ..._. The element introduced by "than" is a comparative clause as complement of _than_ which compares with _others with more moderate views_.

Comment: @BillJ Thank you Bill. These days I am looking through some syntax knowledge. I think I am understand the structure of the sentence. Would you like to tell me whether my analysis correct or not. First of all, there are two complementary elements modifying _protector_, which is a relative clause _what was ... movement_ and two pronoun by comparing. One is _others_ modified by _with more moderate views_, the other is _the conservative hard-line clerics _ modified by a relative sentence _who ... judiciary_. Anyway, thank you so much. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Not quite. First, “protector” has no modifiers. The preposition “of” has as its complement a coordination of two noun phrases which express some things that Mr Rfsanjani protected: _[what was left of Iran’s marginalized reformist movement] and [others with more moderate views than the conservative hard-line clerics who hold sway in Iran’s security forces and judiciary]_. (The two noun phrases are in brackets.)

Comment: The noun “others” is modified by the preposition phrase _with more moderate views than the conservative hard-line clerics who hold sway in Iran’s security forces and judiciary_. And _conservative hard-line clerics_ is modified by the relative clause _who hold sway in Iran’s security forces and judiciary_.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Syntax of fused relative construction with 'what'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/443501/syntax-of-fused-relative-construction-with-what)