# Syntax of fused relative construction with 'what'

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

> *I really liked **what she wrote**.*

According to CaGEL* (Page 1073), ***what she wrote*** is not a clause but a noun phrase (NP). The reason I believe is that the head of ***what she wrote*** is not the clause ***she wrote*** but the noun ***what***. That is, there is a clause in there but it's just that the clause is not the head of the entire thing in bold.

That said, I'd like to know whether the clause (***she wrote***) is a modifier or a complement of the head noun (***what***).

CaGEL doesn't seem to clearly say whether ***she wrote*** is a modifier or a complement of ***what***, although it does say that the relative word part of ***what*** (i.e., prenucleus) combined with ***she wrote*** is a modifier of the antecedent part of ***what*** (i.e., head), as shown in the following tree diagram (Page 1073):

[image]

I don't object to this tree diagram itself, because any relative clause is a modifier (not a complement) of an antecedent, and because in a fused relative construction with ***what***, the relative clause itself comprises the 'prenucleus' part of ***what*** as well as the following clause (e.g., ***she wrote***).

That said, I'd like to know whether the following clause (***she wrote***) is a complement or a modifier of the fused relative word (***what***) in its entirety, which question is not answered in the above tree diagram or anywhere else in CaGEL.

I suspect that, being a fused relative, ***what*** is not just any antecedent but is a fusion of an antecedent and a relative word, and therefore that ***what*** can be construed as licensing ***she wrote***.

Moreover, removing ***she wrote*** would definitely change the meaning of ***what***:

> ?*I really liked **what***.

All in all, is ***she wrote*** a complement or a modifier of ***what***?

### EDIT

After the edit, my question does not go against CaGEL.

*The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language by Huddleston & Pullum

Comment: What does the subscript italic i attached to GAP mean? Is that some arcane way of acknowledging that _what_ is the object of _wrote_?

Comment: @BillJ Please note that I'm not disputing that relative clauses can only function as modifiers of antecedents, never complements thereof. But here, I'm not asking about the role of a relative clause but that of only part of it.

Comment: @BillJ I'm not sure why you say it isn't a constituent. In the tree diagram, it clearly is a constituent, namely, 'Clause'.

Comment: @BillJ Do you somehow think that my original question is about whether _she wrote_ (without GAP) is a modifier or a complement of _what_? If so, what makes you think that? Because I of course was asking about the role of _she wrote_ (with GAP). For example, in _I really liked this novel she wrote._, you can say _she wrote_ is a modifier of _this novel_ without ever mentioning GAP, which is of course included in the modifier even if you don't say that.

Comment: @KarlG It signifies that what and the gap are coindexed, that is, that they have the same referent.

Comment: Doesn't the subscript italic mean null set?  Isn't 'what she wrote" self-contained?

Comment: @Lambie No, it indicates an identity relation (the two things refer to the same entity)

Comment: See this thread: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/464036/what-exactly-falls-under-the-label-of-complement

Answer (score 2):

> That said, I'd like to know whether the following clause (***she wrote***) is a complement or a modifier of the fused relative word (***what***) in its entirety, which question is not answered in the above tree diagram or anywhere else in CaGEL.

No.

This becomes clearer if we consider "that which *Clause*", which is a conveniently *non*-fused equivalent (in formal registers) to the relevant sense of "what *Clause*". In "that which *Clause*", the head is "that", and the relative word is "which". So your question is equivalent to asking whether the clause is a complement or modifier of the two-word sequence "that which"; and the answer is that it's not, because the two-word sequence "that which" is not even a syntactic constituent. "That which *Clause*" is constructed as "that {which *Clause*}"; likewise, "what *Clause*" is constructed as "*Head* {*Prenucleus* *Clause*}", with the only oddity being that the head and prenucleus are fused into a single word. (This is an example of a [bracketing paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracketing_paradox).)

Comment: If "that which" is not even a syntactic constituent, how could they be fused into a single word, "what"?

Comment: Are you saying that: "I liked what she wrote" is equivalent in formal register to: "I like that which she wrote"?  I just don't buy that at all.

Comment: @JK2: Like I said, it's a [bracketing paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracketing_paradox). But you shouldn't be surprised, because your tree diagram clearly shows that *what* isn't a constituent: it fuses a role inside the relative clause with a role outside it. (By the way, to clarify -- "what" is not specifically a fusion of the exact sequence "that which"; rather, it's a fusion of the same roles that "that" and "which" play, and is sometimes synonymous with "that which".)

Comment: @Lambie: The specific sentence "I like that which she wrote" would be awkward -- "that which" is too fancy for the rest of the sentence -- but I don't see how you can doubt that ["that which" is often used synonymously with "what"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22that+which%22).

Comment: You have answered my question then. Of course, "that which" cannot work here.

Comment: @Lambie: The question is about grammar. I only brought up *that which* to show how the grammar of how *what* fuses two functions that are not a single constituent. (Did you really not understand that, or are you just trolling me?)

Comment: @ruakh The fact that CaGEL's tree diagram shows that _what_ isn't a constituent doesn't necessarily mean that _what_ isn't a constituent; all it means is that CaGEL doesn't treat _what_ as a constituent. Maybe, CaGEL's analysis of _what_ as a "fused relative word" is not terribly logical.

Comment: @JK2: I'm sorry, I thought you were specifically asking about CGEL's analysis; after all, you wrote "I don't object to this tree diagram", and you clarified that you're asking this question because it "is not answered in the above tree diagram or anywhere else in [CGEL]". If you're open to other analyses, then I think both "complement" and "modifier" are plausible (as are analyses under which those terms aren't mutually exclusive).

Comment: @ruakh You're right. I really started out asking about the book's analysis, or at least something in accordance with it. But after reading your comments, I'm beginning to suspect that it's rather counter-intuitive or even irrational to analyze _what_ as a fused relative word  (as is accepted as a norm not just in CaGEL but virtually all grammars, traditional or non-traditional). Are you aware of any "other analyses" that treat _what_ not as something other than a fused relative word?

Comment: @JK2: James D. McCawley's *The Syntactic Phenomena of English* regards the *what* as a constituent (see pp. 432-434), and doesn't describe it as "fused". However, I don't see anywhere that it applies a specific name to the relationship of *what* to the rest of the clause; it describes the *what* as taking the "position" of a complementizer (such as *that*), and it counts complementizers as a special sort of modifier (since *that S* has the same category as bare *S*), but obviously that doesn't mean that *what* counts as a modifier.

Comment: I don't troll anyone. I ask questions when I do not understand. For me, the only reading here is:  I really like||what she wrote. And I see no fused anything.

Answer (score 0):

The term *modifier* is normally reserved for non-head constituents of a Noun Phrase, while *complement* is normally used for a mandatory non-NP constituent of a clause licensed by the particular verb or verb sense.

So if you prefer, it's a *modifier*. But I don't think the distinction is of much importance. If you are working on a Linguistics paper, just see what classification works best with your overall analysis and then try to see where the weight of evidence lies.

If you have access to Dixon's *Basic Linguistic Theory*, sec. 17.5.3 has a good, brief discussion on fused relative clauses and some references for further reading.

Comment: Huh? Are you saying that any dependent in an NP is automatically a modifier?

Comment: @Hannah Yes, automatically! That's just customary terminology in syntactic analysis. Everything's either a head or a modifier (though you can subdivide this into modifiers proper and complements).

Comment: Ah, right – then I see what you mean :) Though I certainly wouldn't say that it's "customary terminology in syntactic analysis" to call complements modifiers :) In some frameworks, perhaps, but certainly not in general.